# import specific module from the class by different name as string variable

Tags: python, function, class

I wanna get a module from a class with different name (string variable). However, the content has same form of string as the original module name.
For example

```
import timm
model_configs = timm.models.resnet.default_cfgs['resnet34']  #this one works

target_network_root = 'resnet'
model_configs = timm.models.target_network_root.default_cfgs['resnet34']  #this one doesn't work
```

Since, the target_network_root can change, I might export another network than resnet, I like to call specific module from timm.models as variable. I really appreciate your support.

Comment: Modules aren't imported from classes in Python — you need to learn the lingo of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getattr()

For example:

```
getattr(timm.models, target_network_root)

=> timm.models.resnet
```

Comment: while this works, according to the library the right way is to create model object and read its config.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to load different models form it; this is the right approach:

```py
import timm

list_of_resnet_models = timm.list_models('resnet*',pretrained=True)
#you can fill in this list with some models of your own like: #['resnet34','resnet50','...'] #whatever existing model in timm

model = timm.create_model(list_of_resnet_models[0],pretrained=True)

print(model.default_cfg)
```

later you can pass different indices of `list_of_resnet_models` to load other models!